# hStreams on self-boot systems

Tags: c++, linux, xeon-phi

I'm trying to get a simple tutorial example of [hStreams](https://github.com/01org/hetero-streams) to work on the Many Integrated Cores plattform Intel Xeon Phi (Knights Landing) 7210 (no offload). The [documentation](https://01.org/sites/default/files/documentation/hstreams_way_forward_anl.pdf) of hStreams says:

> Expected to work with self-boot and offload over fabric–Xeon or KNL

So I am wondering if hStreams also works on my plattform. Finally I'am not sure if I would need MPSS (a prerequisite for hStreams) which could only be installed on offload systems.

For the simple tutorial example of hStreams, I am using `example_src.cpp` and `example_sink.cpp`:

```
// example_src.cpp:

#include <hStreams_app_api.h>

int main() {
    uint64_t arg = 3735928559;
    // Create domains and streams
    hStreams_app_init(1,1);
    // Enqueue a computation in stream 0
    hStreams_app_invoke(0, "hello_world",1, 0, &arg, NULL, NULL, 0);
    // Finalize the library. Implicitly
    // waits for the completion of
    // enqueued actions
    hStreams_app_fini();
    return 0;
}


// example_sink:
#include <hStreams_sink.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Ensure proper name mangling and symbol
// visibility of the user function to be
// invoked on the sink.
HSTREAMS_EXPORT

void hello_world(uint64_t arg)
{
    // This printf will be visible
    // on the host. arg will have
    // the value assigned on the source
    printf("Hello world, %x\n", arg);
}
```

For compilation I use `icc -fPIC -shared example_sink.cpp -o example_mic.so -I/usr/include/hStreams` and `icc example_src.cpp -lhstreams_source -o example -I/usr/include/hStreams` which gives me both the execution files.

If I am running `./example` I get the error: `libcoi_host.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. I guess it has to do something with offloading.

It would be great if you could give me two examples. One for compiling hStreams on self-boot systems and one for a GPU as sink system.

Comment: Release notes state that instead of `hStreams_app_init()` i have to use `hStreams_Init()`

Comment: I've installed [offload-over-fabric](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-use-offload-over-fabric-with-knights-landing-intel-xeon-phi-processor) to port offloaded code to x200 processors.

Comment: I think offload to the GPU is not supported until now, but it is on a far roadmap. Currently hStreams does only support offload over PCI. Offload-over-fabric, which is used by 7210 is planed in the "near" future.